# How Do I Load the Configuration File That Contains "host" and "port" Information?

Tags: node.js

I have a configuration file, default.json, in the "config" folder.  This configuration file contains the `host` and `port` information:

```
"server": { "port" : 4001, "host" : "localhost" },
```

Presently, when I run my node.js file, server.js, in a command window, I have to do:

```
C:\...\folder_name>node ./bin/server.js --NODE_CONFIG_=./config
```

to load the configuration information.  Otherwise, I do not have a connection.

How do I load the configuration file in the Node.js file so that when I run it, all I have to do is:

```
C:\...\folder_name>node ./bin/server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

in server.js try to:

```
settings = require("../relative/path/to/config")
```

then it should be possible to:

```
settings.server.port 
settings.server.host
```

Answer (score 0):

To access config files in node.js, you need to make it same like a module. So, your config file will look like

```
module.exports = {
    "server": {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 4001
    }
}
```

and, use this in your `server.js` like

```
var settings = require('../config');

console.log(settings.server.port);
console.log(settings.server.host);
```

Comment: Actually, you can require a `json` file and the object in the file will be returned, without any references to `module.exports`.